# Reusable and independent modules in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have to implement a ticket tool in several applications made with laravel, my question is, if there is any way to do this function in a module with its own routes to existing projects as it is done with angular modules, and to be as it would be. thanks and best regards

Answer (score 1):

In laravel they called it a package instead of modules.
Just follow this laravel package development docs how to implement it.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/packages